# How can I draw triangle on 4 corner of image using canvas JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, filter, pixel

I am drawing rectangle on the corners of the image. For that, I am using JavaScript. Here I am getting the image data from canvas.

```
// Get image data
let imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
let arr = imgData .data;
```

I am finding n which is the length of the adjacent and opposite of the triangle.

```
var n;
if (width > height) {
    n = height / 20;
} else {
    n = width / 20;
}
```

Here, I am using these loops to draw triangle with red color in background on left top corner of the image.

```
for (let y = 0; y < n; y++) {
for (i = y * imgData.width * 4; i < ((y * imgData.width * 4) + (n * 2)) - y; i = i + 4) {
        arr[i] = 255;
        arr[i + 1] = 0;
        arr[i + 2] = 0;
    }
  }
```

Here is the output I am getting.
[image: Canvas Image Output]

My expected output.
[[image: Expected Output2]

I am stuck with first triangle on left top corner of the image. I tried to debug the loops but did not able to find mistake. Can you please help me to find the mistake?

Image Reference:
http://webgl-workshop.com/assets/e826db271aa3c03c69c4aca1e20abf5b.jpg

Comment: Why not actually draw a triangle? `beginPath(), moveTo(a corner), lineTo(horizontal side), lineTo(vertical side), fill()`

Comment: Yeah, there is no reason to do this by coloring individual pixels: draw a triangle instead. It's both easier, and much faster.

Comment: The last `y` in `i < ((y * imgData.width * 4) + (n * 2)) - y` needs to be multiplied by `4` ( the size of a full pixel(R,G,B,A)). But @Niet is completely right, there is no reason to not use a simple path here, and your code was even gonna fail with png images with transparency in these corners since you forgot to set the alpha.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you write the code to complete this drawing task

In .html, refer to your canvas with id="canvas"

In .js file, enter below code. It draw top left corner. Do similarly for other 3 corners.

Let me know if you succeed. Enjoy :) !

```
var canvasElement = document.querySelector("#canvas");
var ctx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
var n = 50; //default at 50px edge length

var triangle = {
    x1: 0, 
    y1: 0, 
    x2: 50, 
    y2: 0, 
    x3: 0, 
    y3: 50 
}

ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(triangle.x1, triangle.y1);
ctx.lineTo(triangle.x2, triangle.y2);
ctx.lineTo(triangle.x3, triangle.y3);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();

// the fill color
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000"; //or 'red'
ctx.fill();
```